# Android.jar is missing anim values in the R file

Tags: android, jar, android-animation, android-resources

I'm trying to reference `android.R.anim.slide_out_left` in my code (I'm building on Android 3.0+), and IntelliJ is telling me it's missing. I tried to compile, and it won't compile. I thought it might be my module setup so I tried compiling with ANT and no dice. So I poked into the android.jar and `slide_out_left` is missing (along with a bunch of other anim values). I'm puzzled at this point because this animation is present when I browse the SDK source. Why isn't it in the jar?

Comment: I noticed that the docs leave it out as well: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.anim.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slide_out_left has not been exposed for app developers. For slide_out_left to be exposed it needs to be present in public.xml of frameworks.

Comment: Is there a reason why it is not exposed to the public for use?

Comment: I am not too sure of that. But there are too many resources that are present in frameworks but not exposed. Very few are exposed for apps